# Is it better to use interpolation multiple times to print out data or use a js expression to concatenate the data in vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, data-binding

This might be a silly question, but I am printing out a very big table with lot's of data using Vue.js, some of which looks best when I concatenate different data bindings in one single `<td></td>` element.

So I am curious if there there is any difference in performance between the two when loading a lot of data.

Here is an example:

Using interpolation:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr v-for="person in people">
            <th>{{ person.firstName }} {{ person.lastName }}</th>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Using js concatention:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr v-for="person in people">
            <th>{{ person.firstName + ' ' + person.lastName }}</th>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

The people array:

```
people: [
    {
        firstName: 'Jhon',
        lastName: 'Doe'
    },
    // A lot more data...
]
```

Comment: There is no difference in the end result.  I think interpolation is easier to write and read, but that is just a matter of opinion.

Comment: @AdamHinckley I have the same opinion, I prefer using interpolation, I was just curious about performance when printing out a lot of data. I actually believe that it might have a slight performance decrease compared to concatenating the two values.

Comment: Unless you are including this in a LOT of micro-optimizations, I don't think it's a performance difference a human would notice .  It might be worth an unnoticeable performance hit for the sake of more readable code.

Comment: @AdamHinckley Got it! Thanks for the help, I will leave my code the way it is.

Comment: Would it not be easy to devise a test?

Comment: If you do it in a computed property it will cache the results (until dependencies change), so if re-rendering a lot...